# Find and Replace only values in Excel (not within formulas)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet pictured below that I'm trying to do a find and replace. For example, I'd like to replace any value in the `Last` column tht's `(4.2800)` with a different value.

When I just try and do a search for that value, it will correctly find all the values:
[image]

However, every time I try to replace the value - it only gives me the option to search within the formulas:

[image]

I was wondering if anyone had any insight onto why this was happening? An image of my spreadsheet is below.

[image]

```
Example data:
+-----------+--------------+
|   Last    |  Settlement  |
+-----------+--------------+
|           |              |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|  (0.0062) |  (0.0075)    |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|  (4.2700) |  (4.4200)    |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|  (4.2700) |  (4.4200)    |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|  (4.2700) |  (4.4200)    |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|  (4.2700) |  (4.4200)    |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|  (4.2700) |  (4.4200)    |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|  (4.2700) |  (4.4200)    |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|  (4.2700) |  (4.4200)    |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|  (4.2700) |  (4.4200)    |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|  (4.2700) |  (4.4200)    |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|  (4.2700) |  (4.4200)    |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|  (4.2700) |  (4.4200)    |
|           |              |
|           |              |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  59.8800  |  59.3400     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
|  54.9100  |  54.1700     |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the `Replace` option has always had only the `Formula` option.
Unfortunately, if you just select that option, you will not only replace the values (which are equivalent to formulas), but also any value that happens to be a part of a formula (as, for example, part of a cell reference).

One work-around:

- Select the `Find` option with values and `Find All`
- Switch to the `Replace` tab

  - The **found** references should still be listed
- Enter your `replace with` value
- Select the locations listed in the `find all` box

  - This limits the `Replace` option to those cells only
- Replace all

**Note** *If the values you are replacing are numbers, and not text strings, be sure to change the `Find what:` in the Replace dialog with the unformatted version of those numbers (what you would see in the formula bar or with the `General` format type).*

So in your second screenshot, you can probably just hit `Replace All` but in other circumstances, you might want to select all those cells found (select a cell in the range and then <kbd>`ctrl+A`</kbd>)

Given your example data, you can just `Replace` with formulas and it will work, provided you use the non-formatted value:

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: How do you select the locations listed in the find all box? I tried just Shift+clicking First row in the find all box and then shit+clicking last row in the find all box. They're all highlighted blue but when I go to hit Replace all or Replace, I still get the same Couldn't find anything to replace

Comment: https://imgur.com/HZx3yv7

At this point, I try ctrl+a and nothing happens.

Comment: @novawaly If your values are formatted numbers and not text strings, then, in the Replace dialog, you have to change them to the numeric value of `-4.28`

Comment: I think im missing something on the last point. When I change it to -4.28, it doesn't find any values whereas without that I was finding all of them

Comment: @novawaly In the `Replace` dialog

Comment: I must be losing my mind here lol - tried that as well:
https://imgur.com/DFRhuA0

Comment: I thik i just got it. I tried restarting excel and it just worked. thank you!

Comment: Note that if you find all `within the whole workbook`, and found values belong to several worksheets, you may select in the list of found values only the values of one worksheet at a time.